# finding the dates between two dates with hours and minits? in Sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

[image]In sql, i write a select statement for find the dates. i am here including the time also my select statement like this....

```
                  select * from test where           
(
(
(DATEDIFF (day,@dat1,req_frmdate)=0 or DATEDIFF (day,@dat2,req_todate)=0)
and
(DATEDIFF (HOUR,@dat1,req_frmdate)=0 or DATEDIFF (HOUR,@dat2,req_todate)=0)
and 
(DATEDIFF (MINUTE,@dat1,req_frmdate)=0 or DATEDIFF (MINUTE,@dat2,req_todate)=0)
)       
or
  (
( @dat1 between req_frmdate and req_todate) or
( @dat2 between req_frmdate and req_todate) or
(req_frmdate between @dat1 and @dat2) or
( req_todate between @dat1 and @dat2)
)       
        )
```

but when i pass the date some time it not considering the time.
 is this query is right?  when i am passing date for example @date1='2013-02-20 09:00'
and @date2= '2013-02-20 12:00' but there is no record in my databse on this date and time
there is a record in my database at req_frmdate='2013-02-20 13:00' and req_todate= '2013-02-20 16:00'

in the screen shot of my table, i have that record in my table, when i pass the two dates
like @date1='2013-02-20 9:00' and @date2='2013-02-20 12:00' the record is coming in my select statement, it should not come the date is different that is the my query.

Comment: And what is the exact question ?

Comment: Please attach your current and desired output

Comment: Gil, i edit my question, and i attach the screen shot please find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want that the records will display only **IF both** `REQ_FRMDATE` and `REQ_TODATE` will be between your two parameter's dates, then you can use `BETWEEN` Clause:

```
DECLARE @dat1 DATETIME SET @dat1 ='2013-02-20 09:00.000'
DECLARE @dat2 DATETIME SET @dat2 ='2013-02-20 12:00.000'
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE
   (req_frmdate BETWEEN @dat1 AND @dat2)
   AND (req_todate BETWEEN @dat1 AND @dat2)
```

Comment: it is not working if i pass @date1= '2013-02-20 13:00' and @date2 = '2013-02-20 16:00'

Comment: where the record is there with  date and time

Comment: if i pass @date1='2013-02-20 09:00' and @date2='2013-02-20 11:00' the recod should not display

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24305/discussion-between-gil-peretz-and-ssasidhar)